# Having issues configuring a LAMP stack inside of a container (Using Podman, but it's similar to Docker in use)

Tags: docker, apache, containers, podman

I'm trying to setup a LAMP development stack in a container (because my OS is immutable. Can't just install it normally) and while I'm mostly successful so far I'm having issues configuring Apache

The Apache config file is located in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but no matter what I put in my Dockerfile it doesn't seem to change. Details on what I'm doing below. I have censored some info such as the root pass and user info for MySQL

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  mynet:

services:
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: ./php-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - mynet

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Amsterdam"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpass"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
    networks:
      - mynet

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - mynet

volumes:
  mysql:
```

The Dockerfile for apache:

```
FROM php:apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli gd zip intl xml

COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY --from=composer/composer:latest-bin /composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Composer installs just fine, but the apache config doesn't actually apply and I'm not sure what's causing it.
I have also made sure the config file is actually there by opening bash on the container.

I am using `podman-compose up -d` to compose the containers

Comment: Is the new file copied into place in the image? If so, put a syntax error into it and see if the error gets logged.

Comment: @RichardHuxton It is not, which is what I meant by "The Apache config file is located in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but no matter what I put in my Dockerfile it doesn't seem to change." but I don't think I was clear enough which is my bad

The config file doesn't change. The contents of my apache2.conf do not show up in the container's /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file